# Filtrar por sentencia CASE

Tags: php, sql, subconsultas

Hay una tabla llamada moviminentos en donde busco listar todos los materiales sin repetir en donde si el tipo de movimiento es igual a ENTRADA que sume el valor que esta en la columna cantidad y si es SALIDAque sume el valor que esta en cantidad, cuando realizo la consulta separa si los muestra pero cuando las intento unis con un case me devuelbe una suma general no distingue si es SALIDA o ENTRADA

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.codigo_material, SUM(m.cantidad) as Cantidad
FROM movimientos m 
WHERE tipo_movimiento="ENTRADA";


SELECT DISTINCT m.codigo_material, SUM(m.cantidad) as Cantidad
FROM movimientos m 
WHERE tipo_movimiento="SALIDA";


SELECT DISTINCT m.codigo_material,
CASE m.tipo_movimiento
    WHEN "ENTRADA" THEN (SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM movimientos WHERE codigo_material=m.codigo_material)
    WHEN "SALIDA" THEN (SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM movimientos WHERE codigo_material=m.codigo_material)
END as Cantidad
FROM movimientos m;




CONSULTA NUEVA

SELECT DISTINCT  `movimientos`.`codigo_material`, `material`.`nombre_material`, `unidad_medida`.`unidad`, sum(
CASE movimientos.tipo_movimiento
    WHEN "ENTRADA" THEN movimientos.cantidad END)as CodigoEn,
SUM(
  CASE movimientos.tipo_movimiento 
    WHEN "SALIDA" THEN movimientos.cantidad END) 
as CantidadSa, `movimientos`.`cantidad`, `material`.`cantidad`
FROM `movimientos` 
    LEFT JOIN `material` ON `movimientos`.`codigo_material` = `material`.`codigo` 
    LEFT JOIN `unidad_medida` ON `material`.`unidad` = `unidad_medida`.`idunidad_medida`  
ORDER BY `movimientos`.`codigo_material` ASC
```

[Base de datos con consultas](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/38PrfMVrWrHXJUDGq3bdxm/4)

Comment: muchas gracias bro

Comment: me podrias ayudar con la nueva edicion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La opción más simple es utilizar un Sum condicionado.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `movimientos` (
  `identrada` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `num_factura` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codigo_material` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_movimiento` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `no_orden` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `retira` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ubicacion_material` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saldo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio` decimal(6,0) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `movimientos` (`identrada`, `fecha`, `num_factura`, `codigo_material`, `cantidad`, `tipo_movimiento`, `no_orden`, `retira`, `ubicacion_material`, `saldo`, `precio`) VALUES
(0, '2021-11-30 16:54:07', '15', 4, 5, 'SALIDA', '225', 'asd2', NULL, 22, '65'),
(1, '2021-11-30 16:52:17', '12', 4, 5, 'ENTRADA', '222', 'asd', NULL, 10, '25'),
(2, '2021-11-30 16:54:07', '13', 4, 22, 'ENTRADA', '223', 'asd2', NULL, 22, '65'),
(3, '2021-11-30 16:54:07', '15', 4, 5, 'SALIDA', '225', 'asd2', NULL, 22, '65'),
(4, '2021-11-30 16:54:07', '15', 4, 5, 'SALIDA', '225', 'asd2', NULL, 22, '65'),
(5, '2021-11-30 16:54:07', '15', 5, 38, 'ENTRADA', '225', 'asd2', NULL, 22, '65'),
(6, '2021-11-30 16:54:07', '15', 5, 29, 'SALIDA', '225', 'asd2', NULL, 22, '65');

--
ALTER TABLE `movimientos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`identrada`);
COMMIT;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT m.codigo_material,
sum(
CASE m.tipo_movimiento
    WHEN "ENTRADA" THEN m.cantidad END)as CodigoEn,
SUM(
  CASE m.tipo_movimiento 
    WHEN "SALIDA" THEN m.cantidad END) 
as CantidadSa
FROM movimientos m
Group by m.codigo_material;
```

| codigo_material | CodigoEn | CantidadSa |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 27 | 15 |
| 5 | 38 | 29 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/38PrfMVrWrHXJUDGq3bdxm/4)
Group by m.codigo_material