# Ventas netas por producto SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, jaspersoft

Necesito actualizar un reporte que muestra las unidades vendidas por mes de un determinado producto en el ultimo año. El actual reporte esta sumando todos los comprobantes sin discriminar si es una factura o nota de credito. Les muestro lo que he armado hasta ahora:

```
SELECT aos_products.name as NombreProducto,
monthname(STR_TO_DATE(month(aos_invoices.date_entered),'%m')) as Mes,
sum(aos_products_quotes.product_qty) as Cant_Prod,
aos_products_cstm.stock_c as Stock,
aos_products.cost as CostoProd

FROM aos_products_quotes
INNER JOIN aos_invoices ON aos_invoices.id = aos_products_quotes.parent_id
INNER JOIN aos_products ON aos_products.id = aos_products_quotes.product_id
INNER JOIN aos_products_cstm ON aos_products_cstm.id_c = aos_products.id 
INNER JOIN aos_invoices_cstm ON aos_invoices_cstm.id_c = aos_invoices.id 

WHERE aos_invoices.date_entered >= 'Parametro de fecha inicial'
AND aos_invoices.date_entered <= 'Parametro de fecha actual'
AND aos_products.name = 'Codigo de producto'
AND aos_invoices.deleted = 0 
AND aos_invoices_cstm.tipo_c <> 'NC' 


GROUP BY month(aos_invoices.date_entered), aos_products.name

ORDER BY aos_invoices.date_entered ASC
```

El problema es que necesito que la consulta reste del total de comprobantes aquellos que sean notas de credito, para que al visualizar las ventas estas sean reales. He tratado de hacer hacer dos consultas y restarlas pero no me ha funcionado... Cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar me serviria, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. La pregunta no tiene demaisada preparación. Puedes darle a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Además puedes realizar un case dentro del sum, para que no sume todos, sino solo los que encajen con la condición. `Sum(case when .... then columna end)`

Comment: Un ejemplo de lo que te comento [Sum condicionado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/500597/filtrar-por-sentencia-case/500602#500602)

Comment: He intentado con CASE pero lo que necesito es restar los campos que sean notas de credito de los que sean facturas, no necesito que me sume campos solo cuando cumplan cierta condicion.